# include keyword not providing filter with extension method

Tags: linq

i want to use include keyword with some selection like this:

```
context.Categories.Include(c => c.Products)
```

i have searched on internet and found following method:

```
public static class ObjectQueryExtension
    {
        public static ObjectQuery<T> Include<T>(this ObjectQuery<T> mainQuery,Expression<Func<T, object>> subSelector)
        {
            return mainQuery.Include(((subSelector.Body as MemberExpression).Member as System.Reflection.PropertyInfo).Name);
        }
    }
```

when i have copy pasted this method in my project and when i am typing

```
context.category.include()//
```

then it is just showing me to use string as parameter like:

```
context.category.include("");//like this
```

i want to use include keyword like this:

```
 context.Categories.Include(c => c.Products)
```

can any body temm me whats the problem???

Comment: just add "using EntityFramework;" to your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put property as string in this extension method:

```
context.category.include("Products");
```

The dafault `Include()` of `System.Data.Entity` also takes string path:

```
public ObjectQuery<T> Include(
    string path
)
```

You can refer to [**MSDN Include() docs**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: sorry bro didnt get u

Comment: can u check out this link http://tomlev2.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/entity-framework-using-include-with-lambda-expressions/

Comment: it will hae 2 overrides check it

Comment: i have edited my code and i have included string path but when i am writing context.userdetails.include().it is showing me string as path and not my extension method

Comment: where have you written extension method? is it in same namespace

Comment: namespace iServiceEntity.Core.DAL
{ public partial class iServiceEntities : DbContext
    { public static class ObjectQueryExtension{}}}